# Android playing Video data from a custom network stream?

Tags: java, android, linux, video, video-streaming

Does Android MediaPlayer can only work with file sources?  I would like play media (video) from a network stream,  but the stream comes in a non-standard protocol, so I have to somehow feed Android MediaPlayer with the data only.

Is there anyway to do that?  I found a few web pages suggesting using a temporary file for the buffered media data etc. but I would like to minimize the I/O usage as much as I can, so I'm looking for a API only solution if there is any?  how about JNI? but looks like the permissions going to be an issue with that also.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Android MediaPlayer can only work
>   with file sources?

No, it handles HTTP and RTSP streams as well.

> I would like play media (video) from a
>   network stream, but the stream comes
>   in a non-standard protocol, so I have
>   to somehow feed Android MediaPlayer
>   with the data only.

That will be difficult. If this were audio, you could use AudioTrack, but there is no video equivalent for this.

One answer is to create a server-side proxy that converts your non-HTTP, non-RTSP stream into an HTTP or RTSP stream, so the existing Android streaming support works.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Android supports HTTP and RTSP video playback for network videos

This link may help you [Click Here](http://androidcodezs.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-network-video.html?view=classic)